# Custom preprocessing in Keras to Roll a Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras-layer

I am sure its a simple problem. I have trying to feed a batch of size (Batch_Size,28,28,1) into an Autoencoder. I want to introduce a lambda layer before the Conv2D layer, that'd pick each sample from the current batch and roll it horizontally.

```
encoder_input=Input(shape=self.input_dim,name='encoder_input')
x=encoder_input
x=Conv2D(filters=32,kernel_size=3,
                          strides=1,name='encoder_conv'+str(lyr),padding ='same')
```

Something along these lines I have done using Numpy

```
import numpy as np
def rotate(my_array):

rotate=np.random.randint(-6,6, size=1)
if rotate!=0:
    new_array=np.roll(my_array,rotate[0],axis=1)
    return new_array
else:
    return my_array

arr=np.random.randint(10, size=(10,15,1))
new_array=rotate(arr)
```

This results the *new_array* to be a rotated version of *arr*. I want to use tf.roll similarly on my input batch.

Comment: In what way does the Lambda layer doc at https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Lambda fail to answer your question?

Comment: What I understood from the documentation is that, the function is applied to the entire batch uniformly. However, in my case I want a random rotation for each sample in the batch and not a uniform rotation in a batch.

Comment: Yes, I'll think about that. The other thing that crossed my mind is that, if you are trying to randomly shift (translate) your images a little, there are standard Tensorflow procedures for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks David. Yes, indeed I found a better way to do it using ImageDataGenerator. What I realized from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64165272/keras-custom-data-generator-from-numpy-array) is that , when trying to pass a numpy array , it needs to have a third dimension indicating the number of channels. This will cause the ImageDataGenerator to treat the numpy array as an image.

```
def my_func(img):

    rotate=np.random.randint(-6,6,size=1)
    new_img=np.roll(img,rotate[0],axis=1)
   
    return new_img

BATCH_SIZE=32

gen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function = my_func)
train_gen = gen.flow(x_train,y_train,batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
test_gen = gen.flow(x_test,y_test,batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)

my_model.model.fit(train_gen,
         validation_data=test_gen,
         epochs=300,
         callbacks=callbacks_list)
```